# Lower bound for a representation on a basis vs on the whole vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $\rho:G\to \text{GL}(V)$ be a representation with $V$ a finite dimensional normed linear space with a basis $v_1,...,v_n$.

Suppose there is a positive constant $C$ such that for any $g\in G$, we have

$$\|\rho(g)v_i\|\ge C \|v_i\|,$$

for any $i=1,...,n$, then do we necessarily have

$$\|\rho(g)v\|\ge C \|v\|,$$

for all $v\in V$? I believe this is not true but cannot find a counterexample.

---

A side question: is this true if $\rho$ is a sub-representation of adjoint representaion?